# Get sent messages with Odoo in my gmail interface into

Tags: gmail, odoo

my Odoo is configured to use google smtp and it works.
I would like to find all messages sent in odoo into my gmail interface. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Email outgoing server can be configured in Settings>>Technical>>Email>>Outgoing mail serversrver

**- Outgoing Server Configuration:**

```
    SMTP Server: smtp.gmail.com
    Connection Security: Select Any One
    Username: Your E-Mail user name
    Password: Your E-Mail password
```

Settings>>Technical>>Email>>Incomming mail servers

**- Incoming Server Configuration:**

```
 **[1] POP server:**

    Server Type : POP Server
    Server Name:  pop.gmail.com
    Port: 995
    SSL/TLS: True
    Username: user@gmail.com
    Password: userpwd

**[2] IMAP server:**

    server name : imap.gmail.com
    port : 993
    User Name : youremailid@gmail.com
    Password : your gmail password
    SSL/TLS : yes
```

**Actions to Perform on Incoming Mails:**

Create a New Record = crm.lead ["define the object name from where you want to this email"]

Now click on the "Fetch Now" button.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this folder: https://mail.google.com/mail/#sent
It works with my Odoo